# CSS background-image not working properly on android mobile

Tags: android, css, background-image, cover

This is the code I am using at the moment:

```
background: url(myimage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:100% 100%!important;
background-position:0 0!important;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size:cover;
background-attachment:scroll;
```

On android I browsed with Chrome. When I scroll down I want the background image to be static. Can I achieve this in some other way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately not, this seems to be a bug which Google has never fixed.

I personally dealt with exactly the same issue last week and ended up giving up on looking for a solution.

[The bug submission](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3301)

For the record, it is also not posible on Safari on iOS.

Comment: it is possible on iOS. its working fine for me. thou thanks for letting me know about the google bug.

Comment: Saw on that bug submission forum that someone managed to do it with background-attachament:scroll. how is that possible ?

Answer (score 10):

Try this. Worked for me after several trial and errors.

```
html {
background-image:url('myimage.jpg');
background-position: center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%; 
overflow: hidden;
}

body {           
height:100%;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: I believe it's the background-size that helps

Comment: This worked for me! And no, `background-size` does not help... it's the `height` and `overflow` trick that does it...

Comment: Go for this solution, this also worked for me after lot of serarchs

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [nullptr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97464/nullptr) there is a fix in the bug report that works. On the post [#23](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3301#c23) by using the `overflow-y` property like that :

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
html {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
    background: url(myimage.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

if you wish to apply the background image on an other element instead of the `body` just make sure the parent contains the `overflow-y` property to `hidden` and the element to `scroll`.

Comment: Works well, I also put `overflow: hidden;` also on `body` to avoid seeing the scrollbar on the browser from computer